# Notify() from runnable

Tags: java, multithreading

I have `myThread.wait()` that is in `synchronzed(myThread)` block. And I have Myrunner that implements runnable. I would like to tell `notify()` from myRunner, but it is not monitor object. Is it possible to get handle of myThread from myRunnable to make notify? Is there any other solution? Extend `myRunnable` from `Thread` and run it is not good for some reasons related on my code specific.

```
public class ThreadMain {
    public Thread reader;
    private class SerialReader implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);                
                    synchronized(this) {
                        System.out.println("notifying");
                        notify();
                        System.out.println("notifying done");
                    }                
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                }                
            }
        }
    }

    ThreadMain() {
        reader = new Thread(new SerialReader());
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        ThreadMain d= new ThreadMain();    
        d.reader.start();
        synchronized(d.reader) {
            try {    
                d.reader.wait();
                System.out.println("got notify");
            } catch (Exception e) { 
                System.out.println(e);
            }    
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: show what you've done.

Comment: Instead of describing your code, copy and paste it - it will be easier to help you.

Comment: I have added code that emulates problem

Answer (score 0):

To `notify()` a `wait()`ing thread you much have a reference to the object it is `wait()` on and you must be able to acquire a lock on it.  I suggest you also change a state which notifying and you check that state change in a loop when `wait()`ing.

The only other option is to change the code of the waiting thread.

Answer (score 0):

Both threads should synchronize using the same object. Also, you should really not use an existing object to syncronize, but create a object to be used explicitly for synchronization, like

```
Object lock = new Object();
```

Also see https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/LCK01-J.+Do+not+synchronize+on+objects+that+may+be+reused

If the lock is to be used to interact with your thread, you can put it in the thread and provide a getter for anyone to use it.